# C# marshaling C++ struct inheritance

Tags: c#, c++, inheritance, struct, marshalling

Let's say I have the following structs in C++

```
struct Base
{
    USHORT  size;
}

struct Inherited : public Base
{
    BYTE    type;
}
```

I want to marshal `Inherited` in C# but the struct inheritance does not work in C#. Is doing the following appropriate ?

```
public interface IBase
{
    ushort Size { get; set; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Inherited : IBase
{
    public ushort Size { get; set; }
    public byte Type { get; set; }
}
```

I simplified the problem here and my structs are way bigger making it difficult to validate the results. Also, the structs are coming from another software that is not so well document making it even harder to validate the results. When using inheritance in C++, are the base class fields before or after the child struct ?

I'm using the `IBase` as a way to enforce the base fields to be present.

Unfortunately, I don't have control over the C++ side (SDK for an external system I integrate with).

Comment: I think it's not unreasonable to expect the base struct to come first in the C++ memory layout, as if it were the first member (but I don't think it's standardized). Have you tried it?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Yes of course I tried and ran the code but as I said: "[...]my structs are way bigger making it difficult to validate the results." That's why I'm trying to validate my hypotesis. Thanks for you input!

Comment: You should probably be using fields instead of properties, but I don't know if this will work.

Comment: I would also suggest you use fields instead of auto properties. And yes, at least as long as you stick to MSVC (or any compiler that's compatible with the original Windows SDK), you can assume base-class fields to come directly before those of the derived class.

Comment: If you're going to do a lot of interop with C++ you may look at C++/CLI

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the C++ side (SDK for an external system I integrate with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "appropriate" does not exactly apply to these C# declarations. By far the best way to avoid accidents is by *not* relying on implementation details of properties and interfaces.  This struct should be declared *internal* and just use plain fields.

The snippet does not demonstrate a failure mode so I'll have to assume that it is a simplified version of the real declaration that *does* have a problem.  The way to check that C# code gets the structure declaration right is to verify that the size of the structure and the offset of the last field are the same in both C++ and C#.  Start by writing a little test program to check that, the C++ version for this snippet should look like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct Base {
    USHORT  size;
};

struct Inherited : public Base {
    BYTE    type;
};


int main()
{
    int len = sizeof(Inherited);
    int ofs = offsetof(Inherited, type);
    return 0;
}
```

And use the debugger to inspect the *len* and *ofs* variables, 4 and 2 in this case.  Do the exact same thing in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var len = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Inherited));
        var ofs = Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(Inherited), "<Type>k__BackingField");
    }
}
public interface IBase {
    ushort Size { get; set; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Inherited : IBase {
    public ushort Size { get; set; }
    public byte Type { get; set; }
}
```

Still 4 and 2, so a perfect match and pinvoke should be good.  When you get a mismatch on the real declaration, work your way backwards on the `ofs` variable, you'll discover the member that was declared wrong.  Do note the consequence of using the property, forcing to check on wonky name of the backing field.  This code will be much less convoluted when the struct is declared by using fields instead of properties, strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You are making assumptions of how the C++ compiler will lay out the class in memory. Depending on your compiler & what flags you are using, this may change. Also depending on the fields you are using. For example, some compilers would be perfectly reasonable to align an object like this:

```
struct Obj
{
    char c; // <-- starts at 0 byte
    int i;  // <-- starts at 4 byte - 4 byte alignment improves performance.
}
```

So you can see how C++ classes might not map to how you expect them to be layed out in C#.

There are flags to control this - you can set the packing in C++ to be 0, then use sequential layout in C#, and then your approach is reasonable.

Your use of properties is not a major problem - as long as you understand how and more importantly *where* the implicit backing field is going to be generated for you by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the real issue in what I was trying to do. The callback I have from the SDK I'm using sends me the `struct Base` and by analyzing the fields inside I determine of which inherited type it is. Then I have to "cast" the base type to the inherited type. Here is what I was initially doing:

```
static T CopyStruct<T>(ref object s1)
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(s1, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T typedStruct = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    handle.Free();
    return typedStruct;
}
```

This way of doing it will never go outside the size of the `struct Base`. Therefore, all the extra fields of the `Inherited` type won't be initialized correctly (reading outside of the copied memory). I ended up doing it in an unsafe manner as follow:

```
fixed (Base* basePtr= &base)
{
    inherited= *(Inherited*) basePtr;
}
```

This way, `inherited` points to the original memory block and may read outside of `base` size.

Thanks for all your previous answers! I actually built a C++ application to validate the sizes and offsets of all the C++ models I had.